# Apache PDFBox: app.launchURL() method doesn't work in PDF when PDF is opened in browser

Tags: java, apache, pdf-generation, pdfbox

I want to create PDF file with redirect in it using Apache PDFBox library. Here is the code:

```
PDDocument document = new PDDocument();

String javaScript = "app.launchURL('http://google.com', false);";
PDActionJavaScript PDAjavascript = new PDActionJavaScript(javaScript);

PDPage page = new PDPage();
document.addPage(page);

document.getDocumentCatalog().setOpenAction(PDAjavascript);

document.save("generatedpdf.pdf");

document.close();
```

When I open the generated PDF in Acrobat Reader everything works fine, but when I open it in browser it doesn't work, I see the message "This PDF document might not be displayed correctly." and no redirect. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not every pdf viewer supports JavaScript in PDFs  (even if a web browser naturally supports JavaScript, it does not necessarily do so in its pdf viewer). Thus, your task won't have a generally working solution.

Comment: @mkl Ok, but any solution would be fine. I understand that it won't work in every browser.